# Confusion about ruby class variable

Tags: ruby, class-variables

Assume a simple ruby program using a class variable,

```
    class Holder
      @@var = 99
      def Holder.var=(val)
        @@var = val
      end
      def var
        @@var
      end
    end

    @@var = "top level variable"

    a = Holder.new
    puts a.var
```

I guess the result should be `99`, but the output is not `99`. I wonder why. Since class variable's scope is the class, I assume the line `@@var = "top level variable"` would not affect the variable in the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@@var` is a class variable of `Holder`. And the `@@var` at the top level is not the same class variable of same name `@@var` of `Holder`, it is you are creating a brand new class variable for the class `Object`. Now `@@var` is shared with the subclass(es) of the parent class. `Object` is a parent class of the class `Holder`.  In Ruby, if you don't explicitly define a super class of any custom class, you are defining using `class` keyword, then `Object` class becomes the default super class of the class, you just created.

On top level, you are defining a new class variable in the class `Object`, like you did, in your posted example. As through inheritance, it is now available to the class `Holder`.

I mean, when you wrote the below :

```
class Holder
  @@var = 99
  def Holder.var=(val)
    @@var = val
  end
  def var
    @@var
  end
end
```

`@@var` is not added already to the `Object` class. Now on the top-level when you wrote the below line :

```
@@var = "top level variable"
```

It means, you are  adding it to `Object` class and also updating old variable(`@@var`) same name as in the `Holder` class one, with this new one, you just defined in the scope of `Object` class.

Remember, *class variables* are shared variables and visible only to the class(`B`), where you defined it and its descendant class(`C`), descendant(`D`) of the descendant class(`C`), so on. But not visible by the **super-class**( `A` as below ) of the class( `B` as below ), until you defined a same name variable in the parent class(`A`), as you are having in the child class(`B`).

```
class A 
end

class B < A
  @@var = 10 
end

class C < B 
end

class D < C 
end

A.class_variable_get(:@@var) # uninitialized class variable @@var in A (NameError)
B.class_variable_get(:@@var) # 10
C.class_variable_get(:@@var) # 10
D.class_variable_get(:@@var) # 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to amplify on what others have said and, in particular, compare the use of class variables with *class instance variables*.  Let's start with this:

```
class Holder1
end

class Holder2 < Holder1
  @@var = 99

  # Create a class setter and a getter for the class variable
  def Holder2.var=(val)
    @@var = val
  end

  def Holder2.var
    @@var
  end

  # Create a instance getter for the class variable
  def var
    @@var
  end
end

class Holder3 < Holder2
end

Holder2.var     #=> 99
Holder2.var = 1
Holder3.var     #=> 1
Holder1.var     #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `var' for Holder1:Class
Holder2.new.var #=> 1
Holder3.new.var #=> 1

Holder3.var = 2
Holder3.var     #=> 2
Holder2.var     #=> 2
Holder3.new.var #=> 2
Holder2.new.var #=> 2
```

Aside: the first two methods would normally be written like this:

```
  def self.var=(val)
    @@var = val
  end

  def self.var
    @@var
  end
```

This works because `self` => `Holder2` when the methods are created.  By not hardwiring the class name, no change is required if you decide to rename the class.

Now this (the use of a class variable) may be exactly the behavior you want.  That is, if you want subclasses to see the variable and be able to change it, a class variable is what you need.

If, however, you want each subclass to have their own variable, which can be neither seen nor changed by subclasses, you need to use a *class instance variable*, `@var`, rather than a class variable, `@@var`.  (Technically, this is not quite right, because one could employ `Holder2.instance_variable_get(:@var)` or `Holder2.instance_variable_set(:@var)` anywhere in your program.)

Compare the results of the code that follows with that above.  I've included an instance variable with the same name as the class instance variable, `@var`, to illustrate that they are as different as are `@night` and `@day`.

```
class Holder1
end

class Holder2 < Holder1
  # Create an accessor for the instance variable
  attr_accessor :var

  # Initialize class instance variable
  @var = 99

  # Create an accessor for the class instance variable
  class << self
    puts "self in 'class << self': #{self}"
    attr_accessor :var
    def our_dog
      "Diva"
    end
  end

  # Create a class method
  def self.our_cat
    puts "self in 'self.our_cat())' def: #{self}"
    "Teagan"
  end   

  # Create an instance setter and a getter for the class instance variable
  def c_ivar=(val)
    self.class.var = val
  end

  def c_ivar
    self.class.var
  end
end

class Holder3 < Holder2
end

                 #=> self in 'class << self': #<Class:Holder2>

Holder2.var      #=> 99
h2 = Holder2.new
h2.var           #=> nil

Holder2.var = 1
Holder2.var      #=> 1
h2.c_ivar        #=> 1
h2.c_ivar = 2
Holder2.var      #=> 2

h2.var           #=> nil
h2.var = 3
h2.var           #=> 3
Holder2.var      #=> 2

Holder3.var      #=> nil
Holder1.var      #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `var' for Holder1:Class

Holder3.var = 4
Holder3.var      #=> 4
Holder2.var      #=> 2
h3 = Holder3.new
h3.c_ivar        #=> 4 
h2.c_ivar        #=> 2

Holder3.our_dog  #=> "Diva"
Holder3.our_cat  #=> "self in 'self.our_cat())' def: Holder3"
                 #=> "Teagan"
```

`Holder1.var` raises an exception because that class has no access to `Holder2`'s class instance variable `var@`. By contrast, the first use of `Holder3.var` returns `nil` because the variable exists for `Holder3`, by inheritance, but has not been initialized.

The expression `class << self` changes `self` from `Holder2` to `Holder2`'s singleton class (aka metaclass) until the next `end`.  Notice that Ruby denotes `Holder2`'s singleton class as `#<Class:Holder2>`.  Also, we do not need to prepend `my_dog` with `self.` because `self` is `Holder2`'s singleton class when the method is created.

Notice that:

```
Holder2.singleton_methods #=> [:var, :var=, :our_dog, :our_cat]
```

This shows that `our_cat()` is a method of `Holder2`'s singleton class, even though `self` was `Holder2` (and not `Holder2`'s singleton class ', `#<Class:Holder2>`) when the method was constructed.  For this reason, some say that, technically, ["there is no such thing as a class method"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217019/ruby-class-methods-vs-methods-in-eigenclasses).  This also tells us that we could have moved the definition of `my_cat` into the `class << self` construct (and dropped `self.`).

Another common way to add instance variables and methods to `Holder2`'s singleton class is to replace `class << self ... end` with `extend M` and create a module:

```
module M
  attr_accessor :var
  def our_dog
    "Diva"
  end
end
```

[Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-extend) mixes these instance variables and methods into `Holder2`'s singleton class.